# Error: RROR] Process or Namespace not found. PM2 Error Linux Server with github actions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, pm2, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I recently updated my self-hosted linux server on compute engine. **Pm2** had been working perfectly along my **github actions** previously. However after update when i restart a pm2 instance from my ssh terminal it works fine. But when I try to restart pm2 instance from github actions jobs then it throws me this error. I've uninstall and reinstalled pm2 but still the same error. Previously it worked fine but now it shows me this error.

So if i run the github action then this error shows
[image]

But when i run the same command from ssh termianl connected to my server then it works fine
[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First, Kill the processes via ssh.
Then, do `pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js` via Github CI.

Answer (score 0):

Running the `svc.sh` with sudo fixed it

Resinstall the service with `sudo ./svc.sh` install and start it

I hope you are clear with this solution